# Directional derivatives being constants in a certain direction

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

While studying more about directional derivatives I came up with a question. According to what I have learned, we take a directional derivative when we analyze how our function $f$ changes as $x$ and $y$ move in a certain direction (it does not have to be horizontal or vertical as in partial derivatives). Assume that $f$ intersects a plane in a straight line. This means that if we take tuples $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)$ is in the intersection (a straight line), then can we say that directional derivative is constant given the direction of the intersection??

My approach was to say that since we are taking $(x,y)$ such that their image is in the intersection, say those $(x,y)$ follow the direction $v$, then we are "going through" a straight line. So, if we moved $(x,y)$ in direction $v$, then my $f(x,y)$ would still be in a straight line and the directional derivative in that direction would just be the slope of my line, right? So taking any $(x,y)$ in direction $v$ would give us the same number, the slope.

Is my thinking correct or I am misunderstanding the definition of a directional derivative.

Comment: Yes, that's very good. You can say that the directional derivative in that direction is constant.

Comment: So, saying that the directional derivatives are constant in that direction gives us any information about the partial derivatives of the points lying in that direction. My reasoning would be that if the directional derivatives are constant at all the points in that direction, then since directional derivatives is the sum of partial derivatives, the latter should also be constant. Is this true? or is there any way to prove it?